# Defining a new section with ConTeXt

Tags: context, section-titles

I'm very new to `ConTeXt`. How can I create my own "mini section", about the size of a paragraph but not as big as a part?

I want the first word in this self-defined section to begin with a particular color (don't care at the moment what the color is). I've read some of the manual and my first guess is that it could be done with the `\setuphead` command, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot, quick mock-up/sketch, or sample code that you've tried?

Comment: @DaveJarvis I don't have any of those. You can consider it to be a generic paragraph. I just want the first word of the paragraph to be bolded and colored.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `text` alternative to place a section title at the beginning of the following paragraph.

```
\definehead [inlinesection] [subject]

\setuphead
  [inlinesection]
  [alternative=text,
  style=,
  color=blue,
  textdistance=\spaceamount]

\starttext

\startinlinesection [title={Lorem}]
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur massa turpis,
semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nunc
lorem, sollicitudin vel sodales eget, vehicula nec mi. Proin ullamcorper rutrum
nibh, at porttitor nunc euismod et. Donec faucibus nisi faucibus ipsum porttitor
pharetra. Sed elementum, lectus nec congue imperdiet, ipsum leo viverra nisi, sit
amet commodo odio odio id nisl. Fusce sagittis lobortis nisi sed consectetur. Nam
egestas, sem ut fermentum convallis, ipsum tellus venenatis augue, eget
condimentum risus quam id erat. Sed metus dui, sollicitudin pharetra pellentesque
sed, placerat eget augue. Mauris sodales pretium tortor vitae rutrum. Proin quam
sem, lobortis tincidunt pretium vitae, feugiat eu lacus.
\stopinlinesection

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]